# Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 3.19 Mapping to a view

Tags: oracle, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to map to a view with latest EF Core provider for Oracle

This is my view

```
create view samson.CustomersContacts as
select c.ID       CustomerId,
   c.NAME     CustomerName,
   ctype.NAME CustomerType,
   ct.NAME    ContactName,
   ct.EMAIL   ContactEmail,
   ct.PHONE   ContactPhone
from CUSTOMER c
     left outer join CUSTOMER_TYPE ctype on c.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = ctype.ID
     left outer join CUSTOMER_CONTACT_MAP map on c.id = map.customer_id and map.CONTACT_TYPE_ID =  1
     left outer join CUSTOMER_CONTACT ct on ct.ID = map.CONTACT_ID
 order by c.NAME;
```

In my DbContext

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder b)
    {
        b.HasDefaultSchema("SAMSON");
        b.Entity<CustomersWithPrimaryContacts>().HasNoKey().ToView("CustomersContacts");
    }
```

This should work, but I get the error

```
    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException : ORA-00942: tabel eller view findes ikke
    at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32& cursorId, Boolean     bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementType, Int32 arrayBindCount,  OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnForExecution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, OracleException&  exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection connection, OracleLogicalTransaction&  oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrianParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean  fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
    at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleRelationalCommandBuilderFactory.OracleRelationalCommandBuilder.OracleRelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(DbContext _, Boolean result)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Samson.Test.Integrations.FrontPageQuery.GetCustomersWithPrimaryContactsIfAny() in C:\Projects\samson\Samson\Samson.Test\Integrations\FrontPageQuery.cs:line 22
```

Maybe it's a bug in the current provider.

I am using Oracle db v. 12.2

Comment: View name casing inside `ToView` mapping? Similar to table names in Oracle, shouldn't it be in uppercase?

Comment: Good question I have tried uppercase